# Java - How to get multiple annotations in a single parameter?

Tags: java, annotations

If I have a method like this:

```
   testLink(@LinkLength(min=0, max=5) List<@LinkRange(min=5, max=9) Integer> link) { ... }
```

How do I get both @LinkLength and @LinkRange annotation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to reflectively access these annotations. Here's an example:

```java
package com.example;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Parameter;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  @Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE_USE})
  public @interface Foo {

    String value();
  }

  public static void bar(@Foo("parameter") List<@Foo("type_use") Integer> list) {}

  public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException {
    Method method = Main.class.getMethod("bar", List.class);

    // get annotation from parameter
    Parameter parameter = method.getParameters()[0];
    System.out.println("PARAMETER ANNOTATION = " + parameter.getAnnotation(Foo.class));

    // get annotation from type argument used in parameter
    AnnotatedParameterizedType annotatedType =
        (AnnotatedParameterizedType) parameter.getAnnotatedType();
    AnnotatedType typeArgument = annotatedType.getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments()[0];
    System.out.println("TYPE_USE ANNOTATION  = " + typeArgument.getAnnotation(Foo.class));
  }
}
```

Which outputs the following:

```
PARAMETER ANNOTATION = @com.example.Main$Foo(value="parameter")
TYPE_USE ANNOTATION  = @com.example.Main$Foo(value="type_use")
```

Here are the methods used:

- [`Class#getMethod(String,Class...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod(java.lang.String,java.lang.Class...))

  - Will only get a public method. To get a non-public method see [`Class#getDeclaredMethod(String,Class...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod(java.lang.String,java.lang.Class...)).
- [`Executable#getParamaeters()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Executable.html#getParameters())

  - `Method` extends from `Executable`.
- [`Parameter#getAnnotatedType()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Parameter.html#getAnnotatedType())
- [`AnnotatedParameterizedType#getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedParameterizedType.html#getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments())
- [`AnnotatedElement#getAnnotation(Class)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html#getAnnotation(java.lang.Class))

  - `Method`, `Parameter`, and `AnnotatedType` (and other types) all inherit `AnnotatedElement`.

The above example makes use of perfect knowledge about the `bar` method. In other words, I knew there was one parameter, I knew that `Parameter#getAnnotatedType()` would return `AnnotatedParameterizedType`, and I knew that the parameterized type had one type argument. This information won't be known ahead-of-time when reflectively scanning an arbitrary class, meaning you'll have to add appropriate checks and only execute certain actions when appropriate. For example:

```java
AnnotatedType type = parameter.getAnnotatedType();
if (type instanceof AnnotatedParameterizedType) {
  // do something...
}
```

Comment: Cool. I didn't know about TYPE_USE.