# How to get annotations in nested parameter parameter?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

If I have a function like this,

```
public void park( List< @myNote("list") List< @myNote("integer") Integer>> l){ System.out.println("park"); }
```

If I use Parameter.getAnnotations() and Paramter.getDeclaredAnnotation,  I can only get @myNote("list"). Are any ways to get the annotation @myNote("integer")?

This may be related to [How to get all types of the inner structures of a nested type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60495176/how-to-get-all-types-of-the-inner-structures-of-a-nested-type)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Java - How to get multiple annotations in a single parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60477426/6395627). You just have to go "in" one more level.

Comment: For the previous answer, there is an uncaught exception. Adding "throws Exception" in main function declaration helps if trying to run the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is code to print the annotations, so you can see where in the reflection API they can be found.

Basically, you call [`param.getAnnotatedType()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Parameter.html#getAnnotatedType--), check if the [`AnnotatedType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedType.html) is an [`AnnotatedParameterizedType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedParameterizedType.html), and call [`getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedParameterizedType.html#getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments--) to get the generic type arguments, and do that recursively.

For each `AnnotatedType`, top-level or nested, you call [`getDeclaredAnnotations()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html#getDeclaredAnnotations--) or [`getAnnotations()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html#getAnnotations--) to get the annotations on that type.

I added extra stuff, just so you can see how it works.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Method method = Test.class.getDeclaredMethod("park", List.class, Map.class);
        for (Parameter param : method.getParameters()) {
            System.out.println("Parameter: " + param);
            printAnnotatedType(1, param.getAnnotatedType());
        }
    }
    static void printAnnotatedType(int indent, AnnotatedType type) {
        System.out.println("  ".repeat(indent) + "AnnotatedType: " + type);
        System.out.println("  ".repeat(indent + 2) + "Type: " + type.getType());
        for (Annotation annotation : type.getDeclaredAnnotations()) {
            System.out.println("  ".repeat(indent + 2) + "Annotation: " + annotation);
        }
        if (type instanceof AnnotatedParameterizedType) {
            AnnotatedParameterizedType pt = (AnnotatedParameterizedType) type;
            for (AnnotatedType typeArg : pt.getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments()) {
                printAnnotatedType(indent + 1, typeArg);
            }
        }
    }
    public void park(@myNote("p0") List< @myNote("list") List< @myNote("integer") @myOther Integer>> l,
                     @myNote("p1") Map< @myNote("key") Long, @myNote("value") String> m) {
        System.out.println("park");
    }
}
```

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)
@interface myNote {
    String value();
}
```

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)
@interface myOther {
}
```

*Output*

```
Parameter: java.util.List<java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>> arg0
  AnnotatedType: @myNote(value="p0") java.util.List<@myNote(value="list") java.util.List<@myNote(value="integer") @myOther() java.lang.Integer>>
      Type: java.util.List<java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>>
      Annotation: @myNote(value="p0")
    AnnotatedType: @myNote(value="list") java.util.List<@myNote(value="integer") @myOther() java.lang.Integer>
        Type: java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>
        Annotation: @myNote(value="list")
      AnnotatedType: @myNote(value="integer") @myOther() java.lang.Integer
          Type: class java.lang.Integer
          Annotation: @myNote(value="integer")
          Annotation: @myOther()
Parameter: java.util.Map<java.lang.Long, java.lang.String> arg1
  AnnotatedType: @myNote(value="p1") java.util.Map<@myNote(value="key") java.lang.Long, @myNote(value="value") java.lang.String>
      Type: java.util.Map<java.lang.Long, java.lang.String>
      Annotation: @myNote(value="p1")
    AnnotatedType: @myNote(value="key") java.lang.Long
        Type: class java.lang.Long
        Annotation: @myNote(value="key")
    AnnotatedType: @myNote(value="value") java.lang.String
        Type: class java.lang.String
        Annotation: @myNote(value="value")
```