# How do I get a nested annotations from a method

Tags: java, nested, annotations

```
   boolean bab(@ListLength List<@IntRange(min=1,max=5) Integer> ts){

    return true;
}
```

How can I get min and max value from parameter annotations?

Comment: Are you trying to access the values from inside or outside the method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java - How to get multiple annotations in a single parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60477426/java-how-to-get-multiple-annotations-in-a-single-parameter)

Comment: Also [How to get annotations in nested parameter parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60499255/6395627).

Comment: I mean access the values from outside the method